# Sharing scope variables between two dynamically instantiated directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9LcYbn1468miu5McgPqR?p=preview

I can add the form to the variable inside the passed in options parameter, but I'd like to bind it to something other than inside the options parameter.

I have a panel directive that create a panel.  As part of the options of the panel, I can specify a directive that the panel should dynamically invoke:

```
(function (ng, app)
{

    "use strict";

    app.directive(
        "panel",

        function ($compile)
        {
            return {
                scope: {
                    options: '=',
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs)
                {
                    el = angular.element('<' + scope.options.Directive + ' options=\'' + JSON.stringify(scope.options.DirectiveOptions) + '\' ' + additionalOptionsString + '></>');

                    element.find(".panel-body").append(el);

                    $compile(el)(scope);
                },
                templateUrl: function (elem, attr)
                {
                    return '/Panel.html';
                },

            }
        });
})(angular, app);
```

This works great, and dynamically instantiates the directive I want without little worry.  Now, I have another directive which consists of another panel, and inside that is another directive.  Both have isolated scopes.  So I have:

```
Panel
   Directive
      Panel
         OtherDirective
```

I want to pass an additional parameters option to "Other Directive" so that the data in "Other Directive" is accessible to "Directive."  The options, as you can see above from the panel code, are being turned into json and being "hard coded" by the panel at the moment.  But this additional scope variable is a string, and turns out like:

```
<OtherDirective options='{"hardCodedJson": "Value"} ' scopeVariableToBind='VariableInDirective'></OtherDirective>
```

yet, the variable 'VariableInDirective' is not being bound by OtherDirective.  Here is some code for those two Directives:

```
    (function (ng, app)
    {

        "use strict";

        app.directive(
            "directive",

            function ()
            {
                return {
                    scope: {
                        options: '=',
                    },
                    controller: function ($scope)
                    {
                        $scope.Comment;

                        $scope.OtherDirectiveOptions=
                        {
                            showcreatebutton: false,

                        };

                        $scope.OtherDirectivePanelOptions = {
                            Id: $scope.options.Id,
                            Title: $scope.options.Title + " Comment",
                            Directive: "otherdirective",
                            DirectiveOptions: $scope.OtherDirectiveOptions, //This gets serialized by the panel and essentially "hard coded"
                            test: true,
                            AdditionalOptions: { "scopevariabletobindto": "VariableInThisScope" }
                        }

                        $scope.test = function ()
                        {
//Function used to see if the variable in this scope was set
                            debugger;
                        }
                    },
                    templateUrl: function (elem, attr)
                    {
                        return '/Directive.html';
                    },
                }
            });
    })(angular, App);
```

Other Directive, which has a form, which I want to bind to the scope above's variable.  I essentially want to be able to chain the variables going up the nested controls, so that I can access them hierarchically:

```
   (function (ng, app)
    {

        "use strict";

        app.directive(
            "otherdirective",

            function ($compile)
            {
                return {
                    scope: {
                        options: '=',
//Have tried scopevariabletobindto: '=form': no luck, have tried a lot of different combinations.
                        scopevariabletobindto: '=',
                    },

                    controller: function ($scope, $element)
                    {

                        $scope.id = $element.parent()[0].id;
//I want this form in this directive to bind to scopevariabletobindto.
                        $scope.form = {};
                       //Have even tried to set it manually like $scope.scopevariabletobindto = { "test" : "test"} with no luck

                    templateUrl: function (elem, attr)
                    {
                        return '/OtherDirective.html';
                    },
                }
            });
    })(angular, app);
```

I want to bind this form to the scope variable passed in to 'scopevariabletobindto', but I can't seem to get it to bind at all.  Any ideas why?

Edit:

It seems that you can actually pass the form property as a function and it works uing the & symbol.

Comment: What about common service for both directives?

Comment: That's an option and I was thinking about that as a workaround, but I'm curious if it's possible through directives without the addition of "middle man."  It's more generic if I don't have to use a service.  Thanks for looking at the question though!  I've been scratching my head for days!

Comment: Would be easier if you simplify your question to a small plunker example

Comment: Added a plunker.  Thanks guys.

Comment: The service is the proper way to manage data between two part, be it controllers or directives.

Comment: So if you want to share data between two components, another file is required?  I find that hard to believe, since I can bind this data to the "options" parameter (ex. options.PutDataHere), but I can't pass in another two way binding variable and dynamically bind the data to it, but instead have to use a service?  Using a service would require tracking the id of each directive and then use an $on binder?

Comment: Did you try traversing scope using $parent?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is naming conventions of Angular. Attributes have to use `kebap-case` so every word concatenated via a hypen, but these are translated in terms of scope to the `camelCase` representation. Therefore, you should convert the attribute name from camel to kebap before writing it to the HTML tag.

For example you shouldn't do:

```
# HTML
<div scopeVariableToBeDefined=".."></div>

# JS
... 
scope: {
   scopeVariableToBeDefined: "="
}
```

Instead do:

```
# HTML
<div scope-variable-to-be-defined=".."></div>

# JS
... 
scope: {
   scopeVariableToBeDefined: "="
}
```

Comment: Where are you doing the conversion in your Plunker? I don't see it. Furthermore, you don't have spaces between multiple HTML attributes, so this will also fail.